# Jquery changing class properties

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting to make a toolbar that fixes itself to the top of my webpage when the page is scrolled down and the header above the toolbar is off-screen. The toolbar however appears to remain set as absolute position regardless of scrolling. Is there an issue possibly somewhere in this code I am not seeing?

```
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
    if (isVisible($('.header-box'))) 
    {
        $('.toolbar').css({'position': 'absolute','top': '25%'});
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('.toolbar').css({'position': 'fixed','top': '0%'});
    }
});

function isVisible(elm) 
{
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    pageTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    Y = $(elm).offset().top,
    elementHeight = $(elm).height();

    return ((Y < (windowHeight + pageTop)) && (Y > (pageTop - elementHeight)));
}
```

Comment: You call `checkVisible()` but the function seems to be called `isVisible()`.

Comment: edited, still not working, but thanks for noticing that part.

Comment: `isVisible(elm)` function takes a jquery object called `elm` so you don't need to put it into jquery function in lines 3 and 4 in the same function

Comment: @user3788161 make a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look on this:

```
$( window ) . scroll ( function () 
{
    var header = $( ".header-box" );
    var toolbar = $( ".toolbar" );
    if ( $( window ) . scrollTop () > header . offset ().top + header . height () ) { toolbar . css ( { "position": "fixed" } ); }
    else { toolbar . css ( { "position": "relative" } ); }
});
```

Complete example is in this fiddle: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yr6cQ/1/)

I hope this will help you.